# How to make part of image transparent including all layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, cs2

I have an image with many layers. I want to define part of it as transparent.

Is there a mask layer which makes all the layers under it transparent or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a group
2. Place all applicable layers in the group
3. Apply a layer mask
4. Paint the layer mask - the darker it is the more transparent. So black is 100% transparent, white is 100% opaque and everything in between is a gradient of that such as 50% Black being 50% transparent.